# Polymorphism with std::variant perfomances

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17

Having a closer look at `__do_visit` in `std::variant` I grew curious about the performances of the `std::variant` polymorphic approach

I wrote a small test program to compare old school inheritance to the `std::variant` one

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int i = 0;
// Polymorphism using variants
class circle
{
  public:
    void draw() const { i++; }
};

class line
{
  public:
    void draw() const { i++; }
};
using v_t  = std::variant<circle, line>;

void variant_way(const std::vector<v_t>& v)
{
  for (const auto &var : v)
    std::visit([](const auto& o) {
        o.draw();
        }, var);
}

// old school
class shape
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
    virtual ~shape() { }
};
class circle_in : public shape
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() const { i++; }
};

class line_in : public shape
{
  public:
   virtual void draw() const { i++; }
};

void inherit_way(const std::vector<shape*>& v)
{
  for (const auto var : v)
        var->draw();
}

// call and measure
template <typename F, typename D>
void run(F f, const D& data, std::string name)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  f(data);
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
  std::cout << name << ": "<< elapsed.count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  constexpr int howmany = 100000;
  {
    std::vector<v_t> v {howmany};
    run(variant_way, v, "variant");
  }
  {
    std::vector<shape*> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
      v.push_back(new circle_in());
    run(inherit_way, v, "inherit_way");
    // deallocate
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On my machine (i7, 16GB RAM), I get these results:

```
variant: 7487
inherit_way: 1302
```

I suspect that this result reflects the fact that the `std::variant` approach creates the `vtable` at each iteration while the  inheriting approach does it once for all.

Is this explanation correct?

Is there a way to reduce the overhead?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated code? The compiler could be a number of optimizations with simple code like this, so the code running might not necessarily be what you intended to benchmark.

Comment: Use some optimisation flags perhaps.

Comment: how did you compile? Runtimes without optimizations are turned on are close to meaningless, and without knowing the optimization level as well

Comment: as you arent using the results of computation one can expect that the compiler will optimize most stuff away completely. Benchmarking isnt that simple unfortunately

Comment: Also, be aware of the _as-if rule_. The operations being measured have no observable effects for the program and the compiler can optimize them away. Namely, the member functions increment `i`, but the result is never used then.

Comment: `std::variant` is not the same as polymorphism (which is not _"old school"_ in my opinion). `std::variant` is more like a type-safe `union`. Talking of vtable with `std::variant` doesn't have a meaning for me.

Comment: Check this article: https://www.cppstories.com/2020/04/variant-virtual-polymorphism.html. There are also some performance measurements presented.

Answer (score 1):

Several things are wrong with this question; and this is technically not necessarily an answer, but I think serves to provide some useful food for thought.

First of all, both the polymorphic classes and the types in the type union (variant) have no data. The sizes of these types therefore are 1 byte for the non-OOP "plain old data" types and 8 bytes for the OOPy types.

To construct at least a reasonable example, you would have to actually make the types hold on to some data; if not, what's the point? You're not measuring what you think you're measuring otherwise.

For instance; running this example on no optimizations, gives the same results as you've provided here.

But compiling with `clang++ -std=c++20 -O3` suddenly, the results are shifted widely in `std::variant`'s favor:

```
variant: 0
inherit_way: 167
```

I'm willing to bet that the compiler is smart enough to see that, hey, the variant case is just a vector of elements with 1 byte in size, but never changing in value, optimizing it out entirely and since the member function of the POD-types are just incrementing a global variable, that is never read, it literally has to do nothing more, therefore the 0 result.

Below, is a better "example question" - though an equally contrived one, but it actually spends time measuring what I think you're actually after.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

int i = 0;
using u64 = std::uint64_t;

static constexpr auto PI = 3.14;

// ignore this, if you don't understand it
template <class... T> constexpr bool always_false = false;

struct point {
  u64 x;
  u64 y;
};

// some imaginary call to an internal rendering function, returning pixels
// written
inline constexpr auto internal_circle_render(auto xrad, auto yrad) {
  return PI * xrad * yrad;
}

// some imaginary call to an internal rendering function, returning pixels
// written
inline constexpr auto internal_line_render(auto width, point p1, point p2) {
  return std::sqrt(std::pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2) + std::pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2)) *
         width;
}

// POD for the win
struct circle {
  u64 xrad;
  u64 yrad;
  point center;
};

struct line {
  point a;
  point b;
  u64 width;
};

template <typename T> constexpr inline auto render_shape(T &&shape) -> u64 {
  using type = std::decay_t<T>;
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<type, line>) {
    return internal_line_render(shape.width, shape.a, shape.b);
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<type, circle>) {
    return internal_circle_render(shape.xrad, shape.yrad);
  } else {
    static_assert(always_false<T>, "unknown type");
  }
}

using v_t = std::variant<circle, line>;
auto variant_way(const std::vector<v_t> &v) {
  auto total_pixels = 0;
  for (const auto &var : v)
    total_pixels += std::visit(
        [](const auto &shape) -> u64 { return render_shape(shape); }, var);
  return total_pixels;
}

// old school
class shape {
public:
  shape() = default;
  virtual ~shape() = default;
  virtual u64 render_pixels() const = 0;
};

class circle_in : public shape {
public:
  circle_in(u64 xrad, u64 yrad, point center)
      : shape(), xrad(xrad), yrad(yrad), center(center) {}
  ~circle_in() override = default;

  virtual u64 render_pixels() const override {
    return internal_circle_render(xrad, yrad);
  }

private:
  u64 xrad;
  u64 yrad;
  point center;
};

class line_in : public shape {
public:
  line_in(point a, point b, u64 width) : shape(), a(a), b(b), width(width) {}
  ~line_in() override = default;

  virtual u64 render_pixels() const override {
    return internal_line_render(width, a, b);
  }

private:
  point a;
  point b;
  u64 width;
};

auto inherit_way(const std::vector<shape *> &v) {
  auto total_pixels = 0;
  for (const auto var : v)
    total_pixels += var->render_pixels();
  return total_pixels;
}

// call and measure
template <typename F, typename D>
void run(F f, const D &data, std::string name) {
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto pixels = f(data);
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto elapsed =
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
  std::cout << name << ": " << elapsed.count() << " " << pixels << " pixels "
            << std::endl;
}

constexpr auto howmany = 100000;

// contrived "random" data
inline std::vector<v_t> create_variant_data() {
  std::vector<v_t> data;
  data.reserve(howmany);
  for (u64 i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
    switch (i % 2) {
    case 0: {
      const auto a = point{.x = 1 + i % 10, .y = 1 + i % 10};
      const auto b = point{.x = 2 + i % 20, .y = 2 + i % 20};
      data.emplace_back(line{.a = a, .b = b, .width = i % 25});
    } break;
    case 1: {
      data.emplace_back(
          circle{.xrad = i % 10, .yrad = i % 20, .center = {.x = i, .y = i}});
    } break;
    }
  }
  return data;
}

// contrived "random" data
inline std::vector<shape *> create_oop_data() {
  std::vector<shape *> data;
  data.reserve(howmany);
  for (u64 i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
    switch (i % 2) {
    case 0: {
      const auto a = point{.x = 1 + i % 10, .y = 1 + i % 10};
      const auto b = point{.x = 2 + i % 20, .y = 2 + i % 20};
      data.push_back(new line_in{a, b, i % 25});
    } break;
    case 1: {
      data.push_back(new circle_in{i % 10, i % 20, {.x = i, .y = i}});
    } break;
    }
  }
  return data;
}

int main() {
  auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
  {
    std::vector<v_t> v = create_variant_data();
    // we definitely want to shuffle, otherwise CPU predictors are going to
    // outsmart us and give us falsy results
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), rng);
    run(variant_way, v, "variant");
  }
  {
    std::vector<shape *> v = create_oop_data();
    // we definitely want to shuffle, otherwise CPU predictors are going to
    // outsmart us and give us falsy results
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), rng);
    run(inherit_way, v, "inherit_way");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this, with `clang++ -std=c++20 -O3` or the gcc equivalent now produces results like

```
variant: 478 14148000 pixels 
inherit_way: 933 14148000 pixels
```

where `inherit_way` can fluctuate up to being ~3.5 times slower than `std::variant`. I'm suspecting this have to do with how favorable the shuffle ends up being. However, `std::variant` never shows these kinds of large fluctuations. So it's fair to say, for simple stuff like this, std::variant outperforms the OOP by a wide, wide margin.

But one has to be very careful when writing "benchmarks" like this, because, even in my example, I'm pretty sure I've missed a ton of things that ends up in the results being misleading. For instance, if one does not shuffle the vectors holding the data, suddenly the OOP-version wins by a slight margin, due to (probably) the CPU being able to speculate that: hey, every other virtual call indirection is landing at this particular address with an extremely high certainty. But data in the real world does end up being laid out like this (and btw, if you know data is laid out like that, one wouldn't even use a `std::variant` here, just use 2 vectors, one holding `line` and one holding `circle`).

One of the reasons why `std::variant` is so much faster than the OOP approach for this contrived example, has to do with indirection. For every element of `std::vector<shape*>` there are at least 2 indirection lookups. One for the pointer of the element, and one for the virtual table lookup, whereas for the `std::variant`, each element is laid out contiguously in the vector, utilizing the cache and "we" are essentially just `switch`ing on some type value and calling the correct function depending on what type. This is so much faster than the virtual call, as the results show.